# Three.js Subdivisions

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying add subdivisions to my json object geometry like this:
What am I doing wrong?

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
 loader.load('/models/susanne.js', function(geometry){
 var geometry = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material[ "feinleinen-schwarz" ]);
 geometry.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );
 geometry.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 0.67, 0 );
 geometry.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 geometry.name = "color-outside";
 scene.add( geometry );
 });


  // Subdivide
  var smooth = geometry();
  smooth.mergeVertices();
  smooth.computeFaceNormals();
  smooth.computeVertexNormals();

  var subdiv = 4;
  var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier( subdiv );
  modifier.modify( smooth );
```

Comment: You are naming your mesh `geometry`, this is also the name of the callback's argument.

Comment: could you show an example, based on my code?

Comment: You can use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z81x74rb/1/)